# Intel XDK service function not returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-services, intel-xdk

This is my function

```
 $scope.login=function(username,password){

        intel.xdk.services.login({"userID":username,"password":password})
            .then(function (response) {


                if(response.statusMessage=="Successful"){
                   console.log(response.statusMessage);
                    $scope.go('/Home');

                }

                else {
                    $scope.errorMessage = response.statusMessage;

                }

            });




    };
```

The log is printing Successful message but the go function not working. If I use go function outside of service function its working.
Go function

```
 $scope.go = function (path) {

        $location.path(path);
    };
```

Comment: Did you try adding a console.log to `$scope.go()` to confirm whether it's being called at all?  Or break in the debugger and examine it?

Comment: Yup the function has excuted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom service prevent this problem.

code like this

```
app.factory('Service',function($q){
 var Response= function (username,password) {
     var deffered=$q.defer();
     intel.xdk.services.login({"userID":username,"password":password}).then(function(response) {
         deffered.resolve(response);
     });
     return deffered.promise;
 };
 return{loginResponse:Response};
});
```